How to unpack a raw binary image file
How do you unpack a .bin file containing a DOS/MBR Boot Sector and another undetected filesystem. I've ran binwalk on it and it showed me the (estimated) locations of data and their types. The output of file is:
chromeos_15393.58.0_reven_recovery_stable-channel_mp-v2.bin: DOS/MBR boot sector; partition 1 : ID=0xc, active, start-CHS (0x16,176,27), end-CHS (0x1e,216,58), startsector 364544, 131072 sectors; partition 2 : ID=0xee, start-CHS (0x0,0,2), end-CHS (0x0,0,2), startsector 1, 1 sectors

From this information I knew there was a Boot Sector at the beginning, but where are the files from the Image and how can I get them. FYI it is ChromeOS based on Android (and Android is based on Linux) the ZIP containing the .bin is located here. I have dded the Disk Image to a USB and am using it from there.
I tried gdisk on it and this was the result:
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.10

Caution! After loading partitions, the CRC doesn't check out!
Warning! Main partition table CRC mismatch! Loaded backup partition table
instead of main partition table!

Warning! One or more CRCs don't match. You should repair the disk!
Main header: OK
Backup header: OK
Main partition table: ERROR
Backup partition table: OK

Partition table scan:
  MBR: hybrid
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: damaged

Found valid MBR and corrupt GPT. Which do you want to use? (Using the
GPT MAY permit recovery of GPT data.)
 1 - MBR
 2 - GPT
 3 - Create blank GPT

Your answer: 2
Disk /dev/sdb: 61341696 sectors, 29.3 GiB
Model: Cruzer Blade    
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 1F1C043E-3E55-B14D-94F1-3962AC2C5E25
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 13815959
Partitions will be aligned on 1-sector boundaries
Total free space is 266217 sectors (130.0 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1         5414912        13815944   4.0 GiB     8300  STATE
   2              69           32836   16.0 MiB    7F00  KERN-A
   3          499712         5414911   2.3 GiB     7F01  ROOT-A
   4           32837           65604   16.0 MiB    7F00  KERN-B
   5          495616          499711   2.0 MiB     7F01  ROOT-B
   6              65              65   512 bytes   7F00  KERN-C
   7              66              66   512 bytes   7F01  ROOT-C
   8          331776          364543   16.0 MiB    8300  OEM
   9              67              67   512 bytes   7F02  reserved
  10              68              68   512 bytes   7F02  reserved
  11              64              64   512 bytes   7F03  RWFW
  12          364544          495615   64.0 MiB    EF00  EFI-SYSTEM

When I saw the "corrupt GPT" I was confused. It cannot possibly be corrupt. And to be fully honest, the names of the areas would make sense for a Linux install (eg EFI-SYSTEM, KERN-A).

What does "unpack" mean? Master Boot Record (MBR) is the first block of a partition, it doesn't include files like archives (or whole disk images/partitions) do.

Do you want to unpack this to use it or unpack it to dissect it or unpack it to edit it?

@Vilinkameni oops. I've edited my question to be more specific. It is a Disk Image. I have dded it to a disk drive but it shows up as empty space when mounted.

Include the information from your comment in your question, along with the command you used to mount the image.

How are you mounting the image? Does sudo losetup -f /path/to/image + sudo partprobe /dev/loopX (replacing /dev/loopX with the freshly installed loop device as listed by say lsblk) avail?

I am mounting it via dding it over to a USB drive and using that

Starting with a downloaded image what commands did you use to put it into the usb, and then how are you accessing the usb?

In my experience there are two nice ways of exploring an image like this on Linux.
One is to extract the individual partitions using 7z, then process each partition individually as appropriate:
7z x chromeos_15393.58.0_reven_recovery_stable-channel_mp-v2.bin

extracts each partition to a different file (with an option to auto-rename in case of naming conflicts); once that’s done, each partition file can be mounted using
sudo mount STATE.img /mnt

The other is to use Linux’s built-in support for partitions in loop devices:
sudo losetup -P -f chromeos_15393.58.0_reven_recovery_stable-channel_mp-v2.bin

This will result in one loop device per partition, typically /dev/loop0p1, /dev/loop0p2 etc. in addition to the main loop device, /dev/loop0. Each partition can be mounted as usual:
sudo mount /dev/loop0p1 /mnt

To clean up, unmount the mounted partitions, and if you used losetup, remove the loop device with losetup -d.
